# JS prompt + PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following js code which will have page reloaded unless user enters the value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var name = prompt("Please enter your name:");
if (name === "") {
    location.reload();
} else if (name) {
} else {
    location.reload();
}
</script>
```

I want to use to pass result into PHP variable. I know that it's not possible, but such function works:

```
<?php

    //prompt function
    function prompt($prompt_msg){
        echo("<script type='text/javascript'> var answer = prompt('".$prompt_msg."'); </script>");

        $answer = "<script type='text/javascript'> document.write(answer); </script>";
        return($answer);
    }

    //program
    $prompt_msg = "Please type your name.";
    $name = prompt($prompt_msg);

    $output_msg = "Hello there ".$name."!";
    echo($output_msg);

?>
```

Anyway I can't seem to be able to check $name for empty/null values. Nothing seems to be working.

Can someone point me towards direction in which I can do the verification of whether or not user entered null value (or pressed cancel) in php code (similar to what I have in js)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so a answer will suffice I suppose.

To my knowledge you aren't able to directly get if the user pressed cancel. But you can use empty() to check if the result is empty.

```
function prompt($prompt_msg){
    echo("<script type='text/javascript'> var answer = prompt('".$prompt_msg."'); </script>");

    $answer = "<script type='text/javascript'> document.write(answer); </script>";
    // Checks if $answer is empty/spaces
    if (!empty($answer)) {
        // Not empty, return
        return($answer);
    } else {
        // $answer is empty, we need to reprompt them.
        // Reprompt them, etc
    }
}
```

This is one of my first answers so I hope it reflects the correct format to answering. I also hope I understood you correctly. I apologize for not being able to just comment this.

PHP Empty() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

---

**As per the comments below, here is a revised setup.**

new_file.php (Creates the file)

```
<?php
// Get Post
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    // Get User's name
    $input_name = trim($_POST['name']);

    // Create new file with name of user
    $file = fopen($input_name . ".txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($file, $input_name . "\n");
    fclose($file);  

    echo "New file created.";
}
?>
```

index.html (Home or where ever the user enters the name)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Prompt for username
    var input_name = prompt("Please enter your name:");

    // If the username was entered
    if (input_name != null) {
        // Post to new_file.php
        $.post("new_file.php", {name: input_name }, function(status){
            alert(status);
        });
    }   
});
</script>
```

Comment: thanks. But I need to check empty case as well, just like in my javascript case.

Also how would you suggest reprompt? 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'> location.reload(); </script>";
obviously won't work

Comment: thought about going recursive, won't work either...  (return prompt($prompt_msg);)

Comment: What do you mean you need to check empty case as well? This will check if the PHP variable $answer is empty or spaces, etc.

I've added comments to my answer to ideally make it more understandable

Comment: I totally understand, I'm just saying that re-promting there doesn't work. What would you suggest using to do the repromt? I tried both echo+javascript code (see my first reply), and recursive call of prompt() function. I've just tested. In case user enters nothing, nothing else happens, while what I need is to re-load the page/call prompt function again etc. I am sorry if my question is dumb, I am still learning. hope you can help me

Comment: All of this is more complicated then it needs to be. I suggest you try using jQuery (if that's an option) to connect your PHP with the UI. Here is the the W3Schools demo https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp I'm currently at work but if jQuery works with you, I can revise my answer to include jQuery. Essentially on page load, you prompt the user to input what you need, then you verify it's not empty, then you post to your PHP page. I'm not sure what the application is so I'm not sure if this would work for you.

Comment: yeah I've been reading about use of JS prompt. It's impossible, but in most cases I've seen people suggesting others jquery use. Since my experience with jquery is very limited, I thought over the solution I posted above. But sadly it cannot give me full achievement of my idea. If you could help with possible jquery solution in your answer I'd appreciate that. And thanks again for everything: time you've taken to reply, your comments etc.

Comment: I'm putting all of this together now, but I'm realizing that you don't need to even be using PHP for this. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: for now I want to write variables into file.

        $s = fopen("f.txt", "a+");
        fwrite($s, $name . "\r\n");
        fclose($s);

later perhaps also do something with mysql.
but it's more of a learning.
Do you have any other tips for putting it all in a file?

Comment: Jessica, I've updated the original post (at the bottom) with a generic way of doing this. Remember to include the jQuery script above the code. This is untested so hopefully it works. Let me know if you need clarification or something.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse yourself. Just path the value as a URL parameter and check it in your server side.

```
 <?php if (!isset($_GET['name'])): ?> 
      <script type="text/javascript">
var loc = location.href;
var name = prompt("Please enter your name:","");  
if (name == "" || name =='null') {
    location.reload();        
} else {
      location.href = loc+"?name="+name;
} 
</script>


<?php else: ?>
<?php echo strip_tags($_GET['name']); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

**However** to void unexpected results, in this solution, I supposed that your URL has no parameters so, in `else if` : `location.href = loc+"?name="+name;` but if there parameters you may make it like `location.href = loc+"&name="+name;`

Comment: thanks! Almost solution I've been looking for
however null version is still output (the case of user pressing cancel)

Comment: @JessicaAnderson very easy, in  checkout the answer's edit.